How to increase the memory size limit for Rstudio in Linux?
I read posts about increasing the memory size of RStudio on Windows like How to set memory limit in RStudio (desktop version)?. I understand that the problem with limited heap size for running R code is present only on Windows as stated for example here R will use everything it can in a Linux environment, which does not limit an application's memory allowance like Windows does.
The command memory.limit() suggested in Increasing (or decreasing) the memory available to R processes returns
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific 

so it doesn't do anything useful on Linux. When I run a program that executes ergm::ergm, it crashes if executed in RStudio for low memory. However, it doesn't crash in Visual Studio Code so far.
I also tried to limit the virtual memory size directly from Linux shell using ulimit -v but it only resulted in the core dumped error
$ ulimit -v 4000000
$ rstudio --max-mem-size=8GB
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

How to increase the memory that RStudio uses on Linux?

Is this XY question? Do you care about some memory limit, or do you want your rstudio not to crash? How do you know it crashes because of memory limit? How do you check the memory limit?
